# How to convert JSON data to Class Object

Tags: string, json

### JS Code.

```
// this is person class constructor.
function personClass(id, name, address, phone) {
    this.Id = id;
    this.Name = name;
    this.Address = address;
    this.Phone = phone;
}
var person = new Array();
person.push(new personClass("101", $('#txtName').val(), $('#txtAddress').val(), $('#txtPhone').val());

AjaxRequest = function ("PersonInfo.asmx/AddNewPerson", "{'person[]':'" + JSON.stringify(person) + "'}", successcallback, errorcallback) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: param,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: successcallback,
        error: errorcallback
    });
}
```

### C# Code.

```
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public string AddProduct(Person[] person)
{
    return person[0].Id;
}

public class Person
{
    private string _id = String.Empty;
    private string Id
    {
        get { return _id; }
        set { _id = value; }
    }
    private string _name = String.Empty;
    private string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; }
    }
    private string _address = String.Empty;
    private string Address
    {
        get { return _address; }
        set { _address = value; }
    }
    private string _phone = String.Empty;
    private string Id
    {
        get { return _phone; }
        set { _phone = value; }
    }
}
```

Problem is that : show response error message following -:

> {"Message":"Invalid web service call,
>   missing value for parameter:
>   \u0027person\u0027.","StackTrace":" at
>   System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceMethodData.CallMethod(Object
>   target, IDictionary`2 parameters)\r\n
>   at
>   System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceMethodData.CallMethodFromRawParams(Object
>   target, IDictionary`2 parameters)\r\n
>   at
>   System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.InvokeMethod(HttpContext
>   context, WebServiceMethodData
>   methodData, IDictionary`2
>   rawParams)\r\n at
>   System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.ExecuteWebServiceCall(HttpContext
>   context, WebServiceMethodData
>   methodData)","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException"}

Please suggest the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
"{'person':" + JSON.stringify(person) + "}"
```

It differs from your code in two places:

1. `person` instead of `person[]`
2. No quotes around person object

Comment: If the answer is helpful, you can up vote it and accept it as correct answer. See http://stackoverflow.com/faq